# JSON vs DATABASE

Tags: database, json, security, configuration

Recently I had to make an application that later on had to be uploaded to multiple web-servers. Doing this I realized that when storing the admin pass and username's into a json file does not need a db connection so it works all the time. Also when saving the configuration inside json I can just copy my application to web-server and then just go to the browser to do the configuration.

When using a database for this I have to configure this hard coded. Than the db connection would be declared inside a connect.php or config.php. When uploading the application I can't use it because there is no db connection. And I cant set A db connection from within the application itself because I can't login even if I could it would be like a car-key inside a closed car.

My dilemma: Is this the right way, is this save, is this efficient and above all how did you guys do this.

What is the best way to store admin login and configuiration data

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to move the password out of source-code into a configuration file. Then leave administration and securing that configuration file up to your system administrators. That way developers do not need to know anything about the production passwords, and there is no record of the password in your source-control.

In other words, it is perfectly normal to have a `config.php` containing a `define("DB_PASS", "topSecret");`

Provided access to the `config.php` file is correctly administered, this method is secure.

Answer (score 1):

Lynks is correct that this is common and is better than having the password in your source control, however if this is a production system that you are designing, I strongly recommend using a different mechanism for user authentication.

Most databases will allow you to use local system users and groups, or external LDAPs to manage your user credentials. Most application servers will have mechanisms for this as well, this is not a new problem. Some systems will allow you to create secure keys (like SSH keys) for trusted users to allow password-less login.

Having passwords in clear anywhere on a production systems is a BAD IDEA, at least use a lossy hashing method to scramble it. Remember as soon as you are dealing with passwords it is YOUR responsibility as a designer and developer to make your best effort to keep it safe. Please evaluate all your options before deciding on the easy solution that could cost you and your customer serious embarrassment later. What technologies are you using? Maybe we can help you find the options available to you.

Remember, nothing lives in total isolation. For example even if this is not a critical system, a lot of places will use a certain pattern for passwords which will give potential hackers a clue for hacking other accounts. If you manage passwords for multiple users, some users use the same password for a lot of things.

This post is not meant as a lecture but a plea for you to make sure you explore all avenues available to you to keep you reputation and your customer safe. Think of it as a challenge, or puzzle and have fun tackling it.

Comment: Well you see the only data witch have to be secure is the settings for the application. They can contain some values witch are not meant for all to see like db-pass, db-user, db-name, e-mail-pass and etc. Also the application back-end is password protected. This password needs to be stored secure and above all it has to be available for the php scrips. That does counts also for the settings.  As I have it now: conf.json witch contains all the settings and admin.json witch contains some admin users and their passwords. The two files are forbidden to see with .htaccess and passwords are encoded.

Comment: I am very sorry I was away. See is if you can get away with NO PASSWORDS in your app. For example, configure an Oracle Database using external authentication (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admnauth.htm). This allows IT to setup a user on the system for your application to run as which Oracle will grant access to without login. Depending on what other technologies you are using see if you can set them all up that way.. Also if you use user groups instead of explicit users you can easily add or remove a user from a group that has access.