# Save website settings in Database vs File(.json)

Tags: php, database, json, zend-framework2

I'm developing a website, and for the settings and preferences like website language, ads layout, some template string messages for emails, etc, I decided to use a Json file instead of saving to database. Now is there any reason why I shouldn't use a json file and stick to database?

PS. I'm using Zend Framework 2 and I'll definitely set the correct permissions on the json file(644 maybe).

PSS. This is not a duplicate of [JSON vs DATABASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138086/json-vs-database). I don't think that I will be storing sensitive data in the json file.

Thank y'll.

EDIT:
YES, I know that I'll be saving to a file, but I wanted to be more specific. I'll be saving to settings.json. A JSON FILE!

Comment: This does not make sense as written. Json is not a way to save a file - it's just a way of writing an object/array as a string. That string can then be stored in a database, a file, a cookie - basically anywhere.

Comment: I think you actually mean "Save website settings in Database vs File"

Comment: You're right guys, it was a little confusing. I'll be writing the settings to a json file. I voted you up ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is yes, there are reasons against using a File (whatever the format). If they are enough to switch to a database, that's for you to decide.

I can think of:

- you will be parsing the file on every request, unless you save the json object in a php cache
- you need to be very careful with permissions: 644 will make the file readable by everyone, you probably want 640 and the file owned by the sysadmin user and the webserver group.
- a file based system is hard to scale and query: if you ever add a new server to the system, you need to keep the files in sync or on a separate/shared filesystem, which creates a bottleneck for the application; you also lose the ability to search the contents with the convenient SQL interface of your database.

The points can probably summarized with: if you expect to grow your application to something that needs to scale, use a database. If you aren't, use whatever fits.

Comment: Thanks mabi for answering. You listed three reasons. for the first one, I should say that it's gonna be stored in session and if it's in session, it won't be read again. The second one is not gonna be a problem either because there's no secret data in it. But the third one is a huge one. Apart from scalability, I guess a database is more versatile, and looks more professional and also I included a settings table in my database design :D. So conclusion is I'll change to database. Thanks everyone

Comment: For future readers I'd note that storing the json *string* in the session is not enough and even storing the parsed data will pain you with increased session size and probably a performance penalty when  your system loads and saves those from/to disk (as opposed to saving them in, say, memcache).

Comment: I wanted to add that I was using ZF2 json config reader. And that there's another reason that I'm gonna be using database. In the table, I've included last_change and last_changed_by columns for logging purposes and therefore querying the database according to these variables is gonna be much easier than searching an array.